# Под какой ОС проще программировать на Python с точки зрения начинающего?

Tags: python, linux, windows

Интересует простота работы с Python, проблемы при установке пакетов, модулей и при работе в целом. Просто заметил, что в большинстве руководств и уроков люди работают под линуксом. Как это можно прокомментировать, кто знает? У меня очень небольшой опыт программирования на питоне под виндой, использую PyCharm. И очень часто возникает множество непонятных ошибок при установке таких повседневных пакетов, например, как urllib..

Comment: Хорошо написанная программа на Python одинаково хорошо работает под любой операционной системой. А большинство авторов потому работают под Linux'ами, что они не менее (а местами и более) удобны для программиста, чем Windows, но при этом бесплатны.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev на вкус и цвет ;-) Мне вот часть задач удобнее решать в венде, часть - в линухе.

Comment: Согласен. Но, например, пересобирать Python под себя однозначно удобнее в Linux'ах. А если хочется иметь uvloop, то Windows однозначно пролетает.

Comment: Удобство для программистов. Кто-то является сторонником СПО. Дистрибутивы GNU/Linux в большинстве случаев бесплатны.
Никакой проприетарщины.
В любом случае, вам стоить попробывать. Главное - не заходите в `vim` :))))

Comment: Возможно, вопрос и имеет право на существование на этом сайте, но текущая формулировка, к сожалению, никуда не годится - порождает священные войны между пользователями этих ОС. Если вы хотите выяснить, в чём могут заключаться различия, стоит перефразировать заголовок.

Comment: Linux / Android :)

Comment: Просто кодить на питоне одинаково под любой ОС. Однако некоторые библиотеки к питону (Pillow, lxml и т.п.) написаны на сишечке и компилируются из исходников, а на винде с этим всё очень плохо, так что при использовании таких библиотек Unix-подобные ОС оказываются проще (Linux, FreeBSD, macOS)